# At what speed will a gas exit a vacuum?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, vacuum, flow, bernoulli-equation

I have limited knowledge about vacuums and fluid dynamics.

Question: Let's say that I have some hydrogen inside of a fully sealed container at low pressure and I unseal it. At what speed will the hydrogen leave the container, and, how fast does it leave at $15, 30, 45,$ and $60$ PSI?
One last question, if there is plasma at around $18,000,000$ Degrees Fahrenheit

Apologies in advance if this is a terrible question.

Comment: If there's hydrogen inside, then it's not a vacuum.  Do you mean the vacuum is on the *outside* of the container?

Comment: He means a container of hydrogen in the vacuum of space

Comment: Sorry I edited it that was my bad.